# How many ways are there of selecting a collection of 70 balls from the box?

Tags: combinatorics

> A box contains 30 red, 40 blue, and 50 white balls; balls of the same colour are indistinguishable. How many ways are there of selecting a collection of 70 balls from the box?

my work is using the generating function:

let $G(x)=(1+x+......+x^{30} )(1+x+.......+x^{40})(1+x+.......+x^{50})$,then  is to find the coefficient of $x^{70}$

I expand the $G(x)$,i was having a taugh time doing the calculate , and i get the coefficient of $x^{70}$ is 1050

I want to know whether the answer is correct and i want to find a easier way to solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Is the answer correct?*"  No, it looks like you have an arithmetic error.  I get an answer of $1061$.  [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28sum+from+k%3D0+to+30+of+x%5Ek%29%28sum+from+k%3D0+to+40+of+x%5Ek%29%28sum+from+k%3D0+to+50+of+x%5Ek%29)

"*Is there an easier way to solve the question?*"  Yes.  Approach with [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) over the events that you have used too many of a particular type of ball, noting that it is impossible to have too many of multiple colors simultaneously so inclusion-exclusion can end after only one round.

$$\binom{70+3-1}{3-1}-\binom{39+3-1}{3-1}-\binom{29+3-1}{3-1}-\binom{19+3-1}{3-1}=1061$$

Comment: I got $1061$.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=choose%2872%2C2%29-choose%2841%2C2%29-choose%2831%2C2%29-choose%2821%2C2%29

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, I had just typed the same in.  I think I forgot to subtract $1$ in the top numbers, having done 42 choose 2, 32 choose 2, etc... instead

Comment: thank you ! this time i got 1061!

Answer (score 0):

One can simplify the generating function calculation significantly.  We have
$$
\begin{align}G(x)&=\frac{1-x^{31}}{1-x}\frac{1-x^{41}}{1-x}\frac{1-x^{51}}{1-x}\\
&=(1-x^{31})(1-x^{41})(1-x^{51})(1-x)^{-3}\\
&=(1-x^{31})(1-x^{41})(1-x^{51})\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}2x^k
\end{align}$$
by the binomial formula.

We can ignore terms of degree $>70$, so $$\begin{align}
[x^{70}]G(x)&=[x^{70}](1-x^{31}-x^{41}-x^{51})\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+2}2x^k\\
&=\binom{72}2-\binom{41}2-\binom{31}2-\binom{21}2\\
&=1061
\end{align}$$
where $[x^n]$ is the coefficient extractor operator.

Comment: @ saulspatz  That's much more efficient than my method. Thank you！

Comment: Yes, multiplying out the generating functions is essentially the same as listing all the possibilities.